# ios detachNewThreadSelector, how to withObjects?

Tags: multithreading, ios

I know that

detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject

can have a (id)anArgument. I have searched it that it can work for NSString.

However, when I pass an integer or size_t, it crashed. Can somebody tell me what is (id)anArgument?

What's more, how can I pass more than one parameter to the thread? For example, I have a function,

-(NSInteger)getIneger: (NSInteger) pageNumber withName(NSString*) filename ;

something like that. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What `(id)anArgument` tells you is that you need to pass an Objective-C argument. Since neither integer nor size_t are Objective-C objects, the application crashes. You will need to package them within an `NSNumber` for this to work. You will also have to alter the method to take in an `NSNumber` rather than the `int`. To pass two or more arguments, I suggest you use an `NSDictionary` object to pass values based on keys. You can define a method that takes in an `NSDictionary` object, unpacks the values and calls the original method you had intended to call.